# How to write Test Code for This Code

Tags: unit-test

```
    PageReference pdf = Page.SendEmailPdf;
    pdf.getParameters().put('id',dealsheet);
    pdf.setRedirect(true);

    // Take the PDF content
    Blob b = pdf.getContent();

    // Create the email attachment
    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    efa.setFileName('BioUrja Trading LLC - Natural Gas Confirmation.pdf');
    efa.setBody(b);

    //New instance of a single email message

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
```

How to write Test Code for This code...

Thanking U

Comment: There are plenty of resources out there on creating test classes if you search. If you start creating a test class then need help this would be better. Please see the guidelines on asking a good question. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have run into the problems of `getContent` not being allowed in tests and of emails not being sent in tests.

To cope with these I'm afraid you have to modify the code you are testing:

```
@TestVisible private PageReference[] pageReferences
        = new PageReference[] {};
@TestVisible private Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] sentEmailMessages
        = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {};

private void yourMethodName() {
    ...
    Blob b;
    if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
        b = pdf.getContent();
    } else {
        b = Blob.valueOf('Fake content');
        pageReferences.add(pdf);
    }
    ...
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    ...
    if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});
    } else {
        sentEmailMessages.add(mail);
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in your test you can assert the values in `pageReferences` and `sentEmailMessages` to confirm that the logic is correct.